# Create individual variables for each row in table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table, codes, with 3 columns (code, email, sent).

How do I call on the first X number of rows of table codes and assign each individual code (in code column) a variable with ordered numbers? (ie $code1, $code2, $code3, $code4)

Now, I will be calling on a multiple of 10 rows (10 rows, 20 rows, 30 rows) at a time so I need to be able to call on these codes individually for other procedures.

Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting the results in an array. Then call on them by using $code['1'] or what ever you are looking for

Comment: How do I do that? I'm new to PHP, never dealt with arrays before! Thanks. I will look it up but it'd be awesome if you could lead me in the right direction.

Comment: Found a similar question that is answered
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9230269/display-mysql-database-as-an-array and for more help on arrays http://us1.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php